# Is there any logging of the basic access to the PC with Ubuntu?

Tags: logging, lock

Is there any logging of the basic access to the PC with Ubuntu. Also that PC is not auto-locked in some time, only the screen is dimming. For example, someone comes nearby, touches the mouse, and the screen get bright.
If there is auto-lock in some time, then something could be found in `auth.txt`. In other words, this is mostly the question about logging of the dimming events, whether it is possible.

Comment: Maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/992699/run-command-when-idle-active can get you started.

Comment: Looks problematic, but I will try, thank you. It seems there is a simple solution like to check a checkbox and to enable that logging.